# Swift 4: SKSpriteNode won't stop on a position

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Here i have a tank with bullets, when the user taps the screen, the tank fires, it's fine

but when the bullet comes out of the tank, it goes above the screen and it won't stop on the touch position

here's my code:

```
for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet4")

        bullet.position = CGPoint(x: self.MainTank.position.x, y: self.MainTank.position.y + 10)

        bullet.size = CGSize(width: 12, height: 20)

        bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bullet.size.width / 2)

        bullet.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        bullet.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true // false stops the bullet on the tank
        bullet.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        self.addChild(bullet)

        var dx = CGFloat(location.x)
        var dy = CGFloat(location.y)

        let magnitude = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)

        dx /= magnitude
        dy /= magnitude

        let vector  = CGVector(dx: 5.0 * dx, dy: 5.0 * dy)

        bullet.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(vector)


}
```

i tried to set `isDynamic` to true, however this makes the bullet stop at the tanks position

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use `SKAction.moveTo(x:,y:)` to move your bullet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably moves outside of the screen because you multiply the vector by 5.0. I also wouldn't create your vector like that, as the division part with the magnitude isn't necessary. Try this instead:

```
let dx = location.x - bullet.position.x
let dy = location.y - bullet.position.y
let vector  = CGVector(dx: dx, dy: dy)
bullet.run(SKAction.move(by: vector, duration: 1.0)) //choose your own duration of course
```

Comment: didn't work, the bullet disappears in a second, thanks for the answer